# Работа с аргументами функции вне функции

Tags: python, функции, списки

У меня есть функция, в которой создается список (данные для списка берутся, считаются не суть как). Пока что функцию я создаю без аргументов в скобках. Вопрос в том, как работать с этим списком далее, вне функции. Функцию я хочу зациклить и получить несколько списков, новые будут появляться в зависимости от времени.

```
def make_lists():
    my_list = [1,2,3,4]
    return (my_list)

for _ in range (10)    
    make_lists()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Я не знаю, точно нужно ли мне возвращать данные способ return. Вопрос в том, как мне получить в дальнейшем my_list_1=my_list (из первого цикла)  , затем my_list_2 = my_list (из второго цикла) и работать с ними?

Comment: `lists = [make_lists() for _ in range (10)]` и дальше использовать: `lists[0], lists[1], ...`

Comment: Как записать неравенство вида lists[x] != lists[x-1] ?  Меня интересует дальнейший вывод этих списков, когда они не равны друг другу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результаты выполнения функции необходимо сохранить, если вы хотите их потом использовать.

Если их достаточно много можно поместить в подходящую структуру данных, например лист или словарь.

Допустим есть функция:

```
def line(a, b):
    """
    >>> line(1, 10)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    """
    return range(a, b)
```

Необходимо запустить её много раз с разными параметрами, которые помещены в список `[(1, 10), (2, 5), (10, 12), (0, 20)]` и сохранить результаты:

```
result = {}
for t in [(1, 10), (2, 5), (10, 12), (0, 20)]:
    result[t] = line(*t)
print result
print result[(1, 10)]
#{(1, 10): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], (0, 1): [0], (2, 5): [2, 3, 4], (10, 12): [10, 11]}
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Результаты выполнения сохранены в словарь. Причём ключи - это использованные входные параметры, а значение - результат, который вернула функция при вызове её с такими параметрами.
Далее в своей программе можно проводить дальнейшие манипуляции опираясь на полученный словарь.